# UWP Adding event handler in base page cause AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have 'BasePage' class which is base class for all other pages in my project.
In initialization, I'm adding EventHandler for 'SystemNavigationManager' for event 'BackRequest'. For some reason that line id causing 'AccessViolationException' when XAML designer is trying to render XAML of class that extends 'BasePage'

I'm not familiar with UWP, so I'll be very grateful for tips.

**BasePage**

```
public class BasePage: Page {
    internal string title = "";
    internal HeaderView headerView;

    public BasePage() {
        this.Loaded += BasePage_Loaded;

        // FIXME: For some reason if this line is uncommented then xaml designer fails. 
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += BasePage_BackRequested;

    }

    private void BasePage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e) {
        bool handled = e.Handled;
        this.BackRequested(ref handled);
        e.Handled = handled;
    }

    private void BackRequested(ref bool handled) {
        //Get a hold of the current frame so that we can inspect the app back stack.

        if (this.Frame == null)
            return;

        // Check to see if this is the top-most page on the app back stack.
        if (this.Frame.CanGoBack && !handled) {
            // If not, set the event to handled and go back to the previous page in the app.
            handled = true;
            this.Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }

    private void setupPageAnimation() {
        TransitionCollection collection = new TransitionCollection();
        NavigationThemeTransition theme = new NavigationThemeTransition();

        var info = new ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo();

        theme.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo = info;
        collection.Add(theme);
        this.Transitions = collection;
    }

    private void BasePage_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) {

        setupPageAnimation();
    }
}
```

### SOLUTION

Just like **Ivan** said, final code looks like this. Without of a trace of bug.

**BasePage**

```
public BasePage() {
    this.Loaded += BasePage_Loaded;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += BasePage_BackRequested;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= BasePage_BackRequested;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't subscribe to back events on constructor but `OnNavigatedTo` and unsubscribe in `OnNavigatedFrom`. Even if it didn't crash it would cause a lot of problems because your back logic would be activated on all previous pages when you press the back button.

Comment: This does sounds more logically. I'll try it.