# System.AccessViolationException when trying to launch UWP program

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I tried to make a new UWP app just to test things out, but now I'm stuck with this exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

All I did after making new Solution, was to make few more pages and added this to the App() in order to achieve global back button:

```
public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

            var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
            currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        }

private void App_BackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = On_BackRequested();
        }
```

And now, every time, it goes to this:

```
var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
```

I get this exception. I'm running out of ideas. Does anyone know what could cause this? In my Debugging settings I have unchecked the: "Suppress JIT opimization on module load" -setting, as suggested elsewhere, but that doesn't help.

Is there something that I don't understant of making an UWP-app, where you can click buttons at the top, and a page would change below them. Here's the XAML behind this:

```
<Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="stackPanel_up" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Button x:Name="eka" Background="Aqua" Content="First" Width="200" 
                    Height="50" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                    Click="eka_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="toka" Background="Aqua" Content="Second" Width="200" Height="50" 
                    FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5,0,5,0" 
                    Click="toka_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="kolmas" Background="Aqua" Content="Third" Width="200" Height="50"
                    FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                    Click="kolmas_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="BackBtn" FontSize="50" Margin="40,0,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="100" CornerRadius="30"
                Background="Transparent" Click="Back_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" />

        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="ChangingArea" Margin="10" Background="AliceBlue"></Frame>
        
    </Grid>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791771/uwp-adding-event-handler-in-base-page-cause-accessviolationexception

Comment: Hello, you can try to move `var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();` to MainPage, that is, handle `AppViewBackButton` in `MainPage.OnNavigatedTo` event.

Comment: @RichardZhang I got the same exception from SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility in  MainPage.OnNavigatedTo.